# Align text next to radio button

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the alignment of a text next to a radio button. It's about a radio button in "td". So I want to align the text "Hex" vertically centered to the radio button, but what I get is this:

The one I got

[image]

I want to make it like this:

[image]

Here is what I've done so far...

HTML

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" class="rButton" /><span class="convText">Hex</span>
</td>
```

CSS

```
.rButton{
    width:13px;
    height:12px;
}
.convText{
    font-family:'Segoe UI';
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7hVzM/)

```
.rButton {
    width: 63px;
    height: 52px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.convText {
    font-family:'Segoe UI';
    font-size:20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Vertical-align docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

Answer (score 1):

Try `vertical-align: middle` and possibly setting the `line-height` of text/input to equal measurements

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` for the radiobutton? and `line-height` for the `span`?

Comment: Apply them to both. You may have to tweak some margin-top for the radio based on your other styles but it's not terribly hard.